# Making a link display a div in a popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am trying to get a link to display a div in a popup.

This my my link:

```
<li><a class="newAttachmentType" onclick="getFiles(true)">Move to somewhere</a></li>
```

and this is the div I am trying to call and put into a popup:

```
<div id="ddlFiles">
    <label>
        Select new CaseFile:</label>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaseFilesNew" DataSourceID="dsCaseFiles"
        DataTextField="Display" DataValueField="FileID" OnPreRender="ddl_PreRender" Width="300px" />
    <label>
        Select old CaseFile:</label>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaseFilesOld" DataSourceID="dsCaseFiles"
        DataTextField="Display" DataValueField="FileID" OnPreRender="ddl_PreRender" Width="300px" />
</div>
```

This is what I have tried so far in the "getFiles()":

```
$('.newAttachmentType').click(function () {
   $('#newAttachmentDialog').dialog({
       autoOpen: true,
       height: 'auto',
       width: 'auto',
       modal: true,
       buttons: {
         "Save": function () {
            var attachmentName = $('#txtNewAttachmentName').val();
            if (attachmentName != "") {
                 var res;
                 PageMethods.addNewAttachmentType(attachmentName, reloadAttachmentTypes, res);
                 $(this).dialog('close');
            }
      },
      Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
      }
   },
   beforeClose: function () { $('#txtNewAttachmentName').val(''); }
 });
});
```

Comment: Why have you got both an `onclick` attribute and a jQuery bound event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the click handler inside of your onclick method. Which is too late to have any effect.

Instead of assigning a click handler like that, just execute the code directly. Basically unwrap the inner function:

```
$('#newAttachmentDialog').dialog({ 
   //Your code
});
```

Comment: thanks, I'm semi new to javascript. I will change it and let you know.

Comment: Well... there is JavaScript and then there is jQuery. You will certainly want to learn them both, but my suggestion is to dig in to JS first, then the DOM. jQuery will make a lot more sense once you have those two concepts down. For a succinct understanding of JavaScript I highly recommend **Douglas Crockford's book "JavaScript: The Good Parts"**

Comment: Thank you very much. I've started reading "Visual quickstart guide : javascript & ajax seventh edition"